# Student hating each student without hating too much?

Tags: society, social-norms

So in my world, I have a university called *The Institution*. It is one of the best university in its era and graduation from it is considered as a guaranteed success in their future. The university offers degrees from Computer Science to Liberal Arts.

Here's the twist: they accept more students than is their capacity. The idea is that they will give them in-house training before filtering them against an internal selection process before finalizing the student list.

What my objective is **to create a norm where it becomes a taboo for a student to interact with another student in the same degree during the internal selection.** For instance, as a wanna-be CS student in *The Institution*, I should actively avoid another wanna-be CS student or I may face social consequences or peer pressure.

At first, I believed the internal selection is enough. Since *The Institution* is a once in a lifetime opportunity and it invites the best of the best, these students would be very competitive against each other and facing your "enemy" is considered as a weakness by their peers and not worthy enough for *The Institution*.

But then I realized, it's not enough as there is nothing that deters them. I realized that it's still OK to interact with other students as long as you don't interact *too much*. If *The Institution* is offering 20 seats of CS for 40 students, it's still OK for me (as a CS student) to make social interaction with 19 CS students (and perhaps make a study group as part of an alliance), but I don't want to interact with 20 CS students as that means one of my peers is bound to be rejected and that may induce betrayal.

So my issue is that I believe my environment is not mean enough.

Talking about study group, the study group is also one of the feature of *The Institution*. Another thing that I want to create is study groups which due to these social norms that will consist of students from different majors. They would try to find where their study intersects and that would be the topic of the collaboration (Humanities may only be able to collaborate on general lessons with a CS student, but a CS student may be able to study on a more specific intersection like linear algebra with Math student)

However, in another issue, I don't want it to be *too* mean or *The Institution* would realize that their practice is counter-productive and they would simply stop the practice of inviting too many.

Comment: Please define social consequence.

Comment: Why on earth would you study with people not in your major? I guess for general classes only?

Comment: Lay odds that cheating will be a major feature of this educational institution. Strangely enough one of the functions of elite universities is bonding and networking so their class can go out into the world and rule it collectively as elites tend to do. This must be a school for Slytherin isolationists.

Comment: @Realdeo I have edited the text of your question to make it read better in English. I assume English isn't your first language and it's a hard language to get right, compared to many other languages. If I have harmed the meaning of your question, please edit in any corrections.

Comment: The drop-out rate in many major universities is surprisingly high especially in their First year. It can be up to twenty percent (20%). This Institution sounds like Tokyo University, but I don't know if they filter their students with an internal selection process on their initial intake.

Comment: @a4android I don't know what you're referring to but where I went to school, the drop out rate of first years in my program was closer to 40%. By the 3rd term, about 30% of the original students remained.

Comment: @Aify, does the example offered at the 4th paragraph satisfy your question?

Comment: @Realdeo I don't see an example in the 4th paragraph (unless you're referring to the seen as weakness thing, which doesn't make any sense to me since facing your enemies instead of running away is usually seen as a sign of *strength*).

Comment: @Aify You must have gone to tougher institutions. Here in Australia it seems to be 30% tops. I quoted the lower range figure. These numbers came up in a conversation, so their reliability may not be full bottle. I can only tell the story as the story was told to me.

Answer (score 5):

I belive it is rather simple: make Institute reject anyone if there is any suspicion that he did something to "help" someone else fail.

So if you were seen learning with other student and he fails, you may be accused of teaching him wrong on purpose, and be rejected, too. If fellow students got ill and were seen eating your fries, you are out. And do on. All in the name of preventing unhealthy, illegal competition!

This will let students socialize with anyone they don't compete with, but will make them afraid to socialize with fellows from their own department. First, any suspicion may get them out. Second, if it's really fought so harshly, maybe it's true? They will fear other students may really want to teach them false things or poison them or something.

Answer (score 2):

### The problem with this idea is that it's self defeating

You have a batch of students, naturally social creatures meeting new people and making friends as fast as they can. You induct them into a culture of mistrust and isolation.

*They move up a year and a new batch of students come along*

They're naturally social creatures making friends as fast as they can. They don't make friends with people in the older years because the older years have been inducted into the culture of isolation, so they don't naturally pass this culture down to the next generation.

Every year you have to start from scratch, you're having to put a lot of work into it when you could just say, "examinations are competitive, only 50% of you will move up a year". To get a properly unhealthy culture in an environment you need to have a slower turnover than a university. It's much easier to do in a workplace.

Answer (score 0):

You want your students to be selfish, elitist snobs? Fine, there is a way to do that. Make your students compete against each other, and make your professors try setting friend against friend in a selective competition. In this case your students would try hard to stay by themselves.

This, however, would have only negative influence on education process.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that the endowment which created the Institution specified that it must admit the top 5% of all secondary schools.  The reason for the Institution's reputation comes from a realization that while its endowment required admission, it didn't require all the students to remain enrolled.  Its rigor reduced the student population and heightened its prestige.

This results in an immense freshman body, who are informed on the first day of classes "Look around you.  Most of you won't be here in the fall."  Immagine that here are 1,000 CS students competing for 20 CS seats.  980 students will be going home.  One aspect the Institution grades on is independence, so any study group results in lower grades in independence.  Only the most driven, intelligent, and disciplined will have any chance of earning a slot.

This, alone, will provide all the motivation to avoid contact.